# How to install packages based on the lock-file with Yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg

We use Yarn to install dependencies. The yarn-lock file is in the repo. If Compared to composer for php, I would expect that when I run `yarn install`, that the dependencies are installed based on the lock-file, and the lock file does not change.

With `composer install` for php, you install always the same version for each package on any environment. I don't see why yarn does not work in a similar way.

I think that with `yarn install` the lock gets updated too often and the file loses its point since it actually does not lock versions. Or am I using the wrong commands?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Yarn 1

I think your best bet is using the [`--frozen-lockfile`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-frozen-lockfile) flag with `yarn install`.

#### Docs:

> If you need reproducible dependencies, which is usually the case with the continuous integration systems, you should pass --frozen-lockfile flag.

Also

> Don’t generate a yarn.lock lockfile and fail if an update is needed.

---

### Yarn2

If using [yarn2](https://yarnpkg.com/) (aka yarn `berry`) this flag is renamed to `--immutable` as of [`v2.0.0`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200).

From the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/install)...

> If the `--immutable` option is set (defaults to true on CI since [`v3.0.0`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300)), Yarn will abort with an error exit code if the lockfile was to be modified. For backward compatibility we offer an alias under the name of `--frozen-lockfile`, but it will be removed in a later release.

---

This way if someone tries to push changes to `package.json`, say upgrade `react` from `^16.8.0` to `^16.10.0`, without updating the `yarn.lock` file. Then it will error out in the CI like below.

```sh
> yarn install --frozen-lockfile
error Your lockfile needs to be updated, but yarn was run with `--frozen-lockfile`.
```

---

To address your comment:

> I think that with yarn install the lock gets updated too often and the file loses its point since it actually does not lock versions. Or am I using the wrong commands?

Yarn/npm is just doing what you tell it to. If you set the version in your `package.json` to `"react": "16.8.0"` it will never update the `yarn.lock` but when using any of the [npm ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver#ranges) like the [Caret](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) (i.e. `"react": "^16.8.0"`), yarn/npm will resolve to the highest/newest version that satisfies the range *you* specified. *You* have all the power!

---

#### Update

I found a small edge case. If you are running `yarn add` in your ci, such as for a ci only dependency, it will update the lock file and do an install for all dependencies. For example....

```sh
# Add ci dep
yarn add codecov

# Install all deps from yarn.lock
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

This will not error like you might expect. Instead, add the `--frozen-lockfile` to yarn add command like this...

```sh
# Add ci dep
yarn add codecov --frozen-lockfile

# Install all deps from yarn.lock
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

Comment: Related github where I argue that frozen-lockfile should be default behavior: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4147

Comment: Also be careful to always use the command flag, if you try to set it through `.yarnrc`, you will never be able to update the yarn.lock at all: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4570

Comment: how can I make updates to a frozen locked file?

Comment: @cyberAnn just run `yarn install` without the `--frozen-lockfile` flag.

Comment: this should be in the first lesson about yarn.

Comment: The correct way to install (only production) dependencies for a specific package in a monorepo is outlined here: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/workspaces/focus/

Comment: @JoschaGötzer Can you elaborate? This thread is **not** about *production-only* dependencies nor *yarn workspaces*.

Answer (score 5):

Check the documentation : https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install

yarn install is used for both installing packages from package.json and installing from yarn.lock. Presence of yarn.lock file determines whether its a install operation or update operation.

> yarn install Install all the dependencies listed within package.json
>   in the local node_modules folder.
>
> The yarn.lock file is utilized as follows:
>
> If yarn.lock is present and is enough to satisfy all the dependencies
>   listed in package.json, the exact versions recorded in yarn.lock are
>   installed, and yarn.lock will be unchanged. Yarn will not check for
>   newer versions. If yarn.lock is absent, or is not enough to satisfy
>   all the dependencies listed in package.json (for example, if you
>   manually add a dependency to package.json), Yarn looks for the newest
>   versions available that satisfy the constraints in package.json. The
>   results are written to yarn.lock.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn lock file expect to work the way you explained
Your yarn.lock file is auto-generated and should be handled entirely by Yarn. As you add/upgrade/remove dependencies with the Yarn CLI, it will automatically update your yarn.lock file.

Comment: ok, but why does my lock-file gets updated on an install, while I didn't change the package.json file or did not run a command to check for available updates?

Comment: `yarn install` may mutate the yarn.lock file. Only with `yarn install --frozen-lockfile` is the lockfile treated as readonly and an error occures if package.json and yarn.lock are out of sync. Yarn default behavior does not enforce reproducible builds, and one wants them esp. on CI.