# YARN START Fails on My PC, But Not My Co-Worker's PC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, yarnpkg

Thank you in advance for your help.

"yarn start" on my PC fails as seen below.  However, "yarn start" works properly on 3 other PCs with the same project.

Any ideas what can cause this failure on my PC?

I've confirmed my PC has the same version of Node.js, NPM, and YARN as the 3 working PCs.

```
% yarn start
...
Failed to compile.
C:/Users/a0866323/.../ContentList.tsx
Line 101:7: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"
99 | type: listType,
100 | desc: title,
> 101 | } as ContentListData;
| ^
102 |
103 | await editList(newList);
104 | }, [editList, listType, title]);
```

EDIT 1:
I've cloned the project to a different location; issue remains.

I've re-installed every component (Node.js, npm, Yarn) with the same version as the other PCs, re-cloned the project repository to a new directory, and re-installed all the dependencies; issue remains.

I've rebooted my PC; issue remains.

Comment: Some things to check are: 1. Run all 3 PCs the same Operating System? 2. Is the yarn.lock file exactly the same on all 3 PCs? 3. Did you install the packages via "npm install" instead of "yarn install"? 4. Does the project still work on a working PC after deleting the node_modules folder and re-installing the packages via `yarn install`?

Comment: Also compare Yarn versions `yarn --version` and node.js versions.

Comment: @Wezelkrozum (1) Yes, all PCs run the same OS.  (2) It was not on my PC, but I copied over their version, deleted "node_modules", re-ran "yarn install" & "yarn start", but error remains.  (3)  We use "yarn install"  (4)  Project still works on their PC after deleting "node_modules" and re-installing packages.

Comment: @k123  Same Yarn versions (1.22.4) across PCs

Comment: Is ContentList.tsx part of a library you import, if so which one?

Comment: In that case there is something else that could still be different. Yarn caches the node_module packages on your PC in a directory. You can clear this cache with `yarn cache clean`. (https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/cache/#toc-yarn-cache-clean) And then once again delete the node_modules folder and re-run the yarn commands.

Comment: @k123 ContentList.tsx was created as part of this project and was not imported.

Comment: @Wezelkrozum  I cleared the Yarn cache, deleted the node_modules folder, and re-ran Yarn install & start commands; same error.

Comment: Then there must be still a difference between the projects on the PCs. You previous answer `("(2) It was not on my PC, but I copied over their version")` indicates to me that there might be more files missing. I suggest to copy the folder from one of the other PCs and do a full compare of all the folders and files to find remaining differences. (You can do that with Winmerge, but feel free to use other software.)

Answer (score 0):

(Thank you 'k123' and 'Wezelkrozum' for your time.)

I was finally able to run "yarn start" after completing the 2 actions below:

1. I cloned the project repository to a location outside of my user's path (C:/Users/)

   - I created a "React" folder directly under the C-drive and cloned the project there
2. I ran "yarn install --frozen-lockfile" to ensure the exact dependency versions in the yarn.lock file were installed and not newer versions

   - Yarn Doc:  https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-frozen-lockfile
   - Where I learned about the "--frozen-lockfile" option: [How to install packages based on the lock-file with Yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630404/how-to-install-packages-based-on-the-lock-file-with-yarn)

Comment: You fixed it but didn't answer your question, what was causing it? My guess is that one of your dependencies at a newer version had an error and the exact version didn't have the error.

Comment: @k123 I haven't had a chance to discover the true root cause.  All I know is that the 2 actions I listed above allowed "yarn start" to finally work properly.